# Inserting content into an existing div with AJAX and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm currently using the following code to insert generated content into a DIV:

```
$(this).next("div").load("getcontent","contentid="+id");
```

However, at the moment this replaces any content in the DIV by the content returned by getpost. What I would like is to insert the content at the start of the next div. Is this possible/easy with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Use [prepend](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend), e.g:

```
$.get('getcontent',"contentid="+id, function(html) {
    $(this).next("div").prepend(html);
});
```